# An expression for equilibrium constant of isotope reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, isotope

Consider the isotope exchange reaction:
$$\ce{C ^{16}O + 1/2 ^{18}O {}^{18}O <=> C^{18}O + 1/2 ^{16}O^{16}O}$$

The equilibrium constant for the reaction is:

$$K=\frac{\prod (a_i)^{n_i}_{products}}{\prod(a_i)^{n_i}_{reactants}} = \frac{[a(\ce{ ^{16}O ^{16}O})]^{1/2} a(\ce{C ^{18}O})}{[a(\ce{ ^{18}O ^{18}O})]^{1/2}a(\ce{C ^{16}O})} $$

In [this chapter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi4v6Cy19TqAhXbl3IEHaz3CkMQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdigitalrepository.unm.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Ffilename%3D3%26article%3D1000%26context%3Dunm_oer%26type%3Dadditional&usg=AOvVaw3RzI2ah2fqgYv2MgdkEj6E), from Eq. (3.3) to (3.4) the following simplification is done for the equilibrium constant:

Since activity coefficients are close to 1, one can write (eq. 3.4):

$$K= \frac{(\ce{ ^{18}O/ ^{16}O})_\ce{CO}}{(\ce{^{18}O/ ^{16}O})_\ce{O2}} = \alpha_\ce{CO-O2}$$

I understand that activity coefficient of $1$ allows us to replace it by concentration, so $a(\ce{^{16}O ^{16}O})=[\ce{^{16}O ^{16}O}] \stackrel{?}{=}\frac{1}{2} [\ce{^{16} O}]_\ce{O2}$. I don't understand how the power $1/2$ gets converted to a power $1$.

For reference, here are the chemical equation and the equilibrium expression in the original form from the linked textbook:

> [image: Blockquote]

> [image]

Comment: Your starting equation is wrong - should be without 1/2.

Comment: The 1/2 is needed to balance the oxygen isotopes on the left and right side. This equation is also Eq. (3.2) in the linked chapter.

Comment: And it should be with single exchanged oxygen in O2.

Comment: That is irrelevant; you can multiply the whole equation with any number $n$ and then ask the same question about $K^{1/n}$ when $K$ is the equilibrium constant of the multiplied equation.

Comment: The equilibrium expression written in the book is for a reaction that is not the one you wrote. You should use the correct reaction. Notice that the desired equilibrium constant  depends on dioxygen that has both a labeled and an unlabeled oxygen atom. That species is not present in your equation. I believe this is what @Mithoron is trying to tell you.

Comment: @Mithoron I edited the question to include the equation and equilibrium expression given in the textbook. They decided not to look at the mixed species (don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

The notation is strange, but the result is correct.

For example, if you have 100 dioxygen molecules (so 200 oxygen atoms), 10% of the atoms are of the 16-O isotope and we distribute them randomly, we get the following:

- 81 both 18-O
- 18 mixed species
- 1 both 16-O

To visualize this, take all the numbers from 00 to 99, and say that the digit zero represents the 16-O. Only one number has two zeros (00), and 18 numbers have exactly one zero (01-09 and, counted by tens, 10-90).

The ratio of 18-O to 16-O is 9:1. The ratio of heavy dioxygen (both O-18) to light dioxygen (both O-16) is 81:1, i.e. the square of the atom ratio. That is why the square root disappears in the last step of the derivation.